# Automatically updating ModelBuilder tools when submodels are modified?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.5

I have some pretty complex ModelBuilder tools I have developed that contain a lot of nested sub-models.  These submodels are sometimes modified, such as in value lists or code blocks, but the tools using them don't update their behavior unless I delete the modified submodel from those tools, then copy it back in and reconnect everything.  This can be particularly tedious for sub-models that have a lot of parameters.

Is there any way to tell a parent tool to automatically "refresh" its connections to sub-models it uses so that any changes in the sub-model are integrated into the parent model?